# New display, blurry text/desktop

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-11

I bought a TCL C835 (Mini LED 4K TV to use as PC monitor replacing my old Samsung Q80R (4K UHD TV - 2019), but my text/desktop is very blurry and texts almost blend in their backgrounds depending on their colors.

This happened before when I got the Q80R and I remember changing the HDMI Input to "Enhanced" and reinstalling the display drivers fixed it, but that doesn't seem to work with the TCL.

Everything looks as if the PC is rendering in 1080p and upscaling to 4k. And this is the weird part, if I **uninstall** the graphics driver (Nvidia) the desktop blinks and while it has no graphics driver installed everything looks sharp and clean.

It only lasts until I restart the PC, when an old version of the graphics driver is reinstalled automatically by windows 11, and everything looks blurry again.

[image: Blurry Opera]

I've tried many blurry fixes around, reinstalling the display drivers, reset the PC, regedit, etc, none worked or looked as good as when I uninstall the graphics driver until its back again.

How can I fix this?

Notes edited in from commments:

Old situation:

- Samsung Q80R TV (2019)

  4k resolution

  Using HDMI as input (it only has HDMI)

New situation:

- TCL C835 mini LED 4K TV

  Using HDMI 1.4 as input

Unchanged (@OP, please confirm)

- Same 3840x2160 resolution

  Same HDMI cable

  Same scaling

Comment: Not an answer, but some things to consider. 1. Does this alkso happen when you do not use DPI scaling. (probably highly desired on 4K, but half the fuzzie screen issues I have run into where do to scaling going wrong).  2. Post driver install, what is the output. Is it 4k, or less and is the display trying to do some internal scaling to fill fullscreen?   3. One a 4K screen I do not expect VGA or DVI, but to make sure: DP, HDMI ir USB-C as connection, with no inbetween convertor?

Comment: @Hennes 150% Scaling, but no matter what I use, its always blurry, display at 3840x2160 and just a simple HDMI cable, nothing in between.